# Regular Expression and Replace

Tags: regex

I'm fairly new to Regular Expressions and I'm really struggling with this. I can't give up though because I'm sure there must be an easy answer.

I Have a full Salutation which looks like this:

`Mr A Smith`

I want to convert it to `Mr Smith`. The trouble is that it could be `MR A B SMITH` or `MR A B C SMITH` etc. or even already `MR SMITH`.

For simplification assume I'm allowing for just `MRS` too.

I've tried `^((MR|MRS)\s)([A-Z]{1}\s)*([A-Z]{3,})$` with a Replace Pattern of `$1$3` but it keeps finding each of the middle initials as $2, $3, $4 etc. I need to force it to see ANY NUMBER of Initial/Space pairs as just $2, so Surname is always $3.

I'm testing in VBScript but will be using VBA when working.

Comment: Actually, your regex is fine, just add `?:` to the middle group to stop it from being captured.

Comment: @georg I tried ^((MR|MRS)\s)([A-Z]{1}\s?)*([A-Z]{3,})$ with my Input of "MR A B C D SMITH" and that somehow made it return "MR M" which I don't understand at all...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can search for this regex:

```
(MRS?)(\s+[A-Z])*\s+([A-Za-z]{3,})
```

And replace by:

```
$1 $3
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nY4dH2/1)

Comment: Excellent! I had to tweak it to allow for MR or MRS and I don't need to allow for lower case because it will be made Proper afterwards - but all tests worked perfectly with this: (MR|MRS?)(\s+[A-Z])*\s+([A-Z]{3,}). Thank you!